# App Center Web Preview not showing Permissions.

Tags: facebook, center

While editing the App Center page for the app and using preview to check it out before submission, the permission values are not being displayed.

Is this something that happens after the submission process, or is there something going wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, I think my question is related: [How can I test if my App Center page correctly signs in a new user?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10625830/how-can-i-test-if-my-app-center-page-correctly-signs-in-a-new-user)